# Ruby GuardFile - Why does the process restart twice

Tags: ruby, guard

I have a Guard setup (Ruby gem that reacts to filesystem events - https://github.com/guard/) that compiles coffee files to Javascript and also restarts the node.js server on changes to relevant js files.

Here is my Guardfile from my project directory:

```
guard 'process',
  :name => 'SPCRM Server',
  :command => 'node --debug server/js/app.js' do
    watch(%r{^server/js/.+\.js$})
  end

guard 'coffeescript',
  :input => 'app/coffee',
  :output => 'app/js'

guard 'coffeescript',
  :input => 'server/coffee',
  :output => 'server/js'
```

When I change a relevant .coffee file (so that a server/js/ file is updated) the process is restarted **twice**. Modifying by hand a server/js/*.js file and it is only restarting once (as expected) leading me to believe it does two passes for some reason.

Here is the output running with **guard -d**

```
debugger listening on port 5858DEBUG (19:30:26): Guard::CoffeeScript#run_on_change with ["server/coffee/app.coffee"]
DEBUG (19:30:26): Hook :run_on_change_begin executed for Guard::CoffeeScript
DEBUG (19:30:26): Command execution: command -v nodejs 2>/dev/null
DEBUG (19:30:26): Command execution: command -v node 2>/dev/null
DEBUG (19:30:26): Command execution: command -v /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/jsc 2>/dev/null
DEBUG (19:30:26): Command execution: command -v js 2>/dev/null
DEBUG (19:30:26): Command execution: command -v cscript 2>/dev/null
Compile server/coffee/app.coffee
Successfully generated server/js/app.js
Stopping process SPCRM Server
Stopped process SPCRM Server
Starting process SPCRM Server
Started process SPCRM Server
DEBUG (19:30:27): Hook :run_on_change_end executed for Guard::CoffeeScript
DEBUG (19:30:27): Guard::Process#run_on_change with ["server"]
DEBUG (19:30:27): Hook :run_on_change_begin executed for Guard::Process
Stopping process SPCRM Server
Stopped process SPCRM Server
Starting process SPCRM Server
Started process SPCRM Server
DEBUG (19:30:27): Hook :run_on_change_end executed for Guard::Process
debugger listening on port 5858
```

My knowledge of Ruby is limited so whilst I have read the FAQs, examples, wikis, rubydocs I still none the wiser. It would seem that after the first match the rules cascade and then are applied again.

My expectation would be this:

1. Update file in my editor and save server/coffee/app.coffee
2. Guard recognizes this and the Guard-Coffeescript plugin overwrites server/js/app.js
3. Guard recognizes server/js/app.js has changed and Guard-Process restarts node server.

Can anyone help me solve this minor annoyance or enlighten me on how Guard is processing my Guardfile/FS events?

This is using fresh Ruby 1.9 (installed via Homebrew), latest Guard and plugins, including the fs event gem, on Mac OX Lion.

Comment: I've had this problem with the watchdog library in python too... I'm guessing it's because either the filesystem raises the event twice, or my editor is saving the file twice. Don't know which.